# Spring cloud config client Could not resolve placeholder 'driverClassName' in value "${driverClassName}

Tags: spring, server, cloud, config

i have config server with local file

D:\Projects\config-server1\src\main\resources\config\db.properties

```
driverClassName=com.mysql.driver
username=rootdb
password=mypwddb
```

And config server application.properties

```
server.port=8888
spring.profiles.active=native
```

when i go to http://localhost:8888/db/default  server return

```
{"name":"db","profiles":["default"],"label":null,"version":null,"state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"classpath:/config/db.properties","source":{"driverClassName":"com.mysql.driver","username":"rootdb","password":"qwaszxdb"}},{"name":"classpath:/application.properties","source":{"server.port":"8888","spring.profiles.active":"native"}}]}
```

next step, i create config client

application.properties of my config client

```
server.port=8030
spring.application.name=db
spring.profiles.active=default
spring.cloud.config.url=localhost:8888
```

Main class nothing special

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigClient7Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigClient7Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And my controller, when i try to use @Value()

```
package com;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class DbController {

    @Value("${driverClassName}")
    String driverClassName;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String myMethod(){
        return driverClassName;
    }
}
```

I've tried hundreds of options, but I always get an error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dbController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'driverClassName' in value "${driverClassName}"
```

I spent all day looking for an error, but in the end I didn't find anything
Can anyone suggest what the problem is?

Comment: I prepared another project, the server starts up normally, and the client gives a similar error again. If it's not difficult, please see the archive  [link](https://github.com/129z7k/tmp)

Comment: maybe someone will have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

solved
my pom.xml and bootstrap.propertry was wrong